# Con un datatable, quiero escribir en una primer columna un id y en una segunda columna el idSiguiente de la primer columna, ejemplo:

Tags: c#, datatables

Con el `datatable` quiero conseguir lo siguiente:

```
idPregunta      idPreguntaSiguiente

    1                    2
    2                    3
    3                    4
    4                    5
    5                    0
```

Pero estoy consiguiendo esto:

```
idPregunta     idPreguntaSiguiente

    1                    
    2                    2
    3                    3
    4                    4
    5                    5
```

Este es mi código:

```
    protected DataTable creartablaParaIdSig(DataTable TablaIdSig) {

        DataTable nuevaTablaIdSig = new DataTable();

        //DataTable pregunta = resultados.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataColumn col in TablaIdSig.Columns) {
            DataColumn colNew = new DataColumn(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
            nuevaTablaIdSig.Columns.Add(colNew);
        }

        DataColumn idPregSig = new DataColumn("idPregSig");
        nuevaTablaIdSig.Columns.Add(idPregSig);

        var bandera = 0;



        foreach (DataRow dr in TablaIdSig.Rows) {

            DataRow row = nuevaTablaIdSig.NewRow();
            row["idPregunta"] = dr["idPregunta"];
            nuevaTablaIdSig.Rows.Add(row);

            var preguntaSiguiente = row["idPregunta"];

            if (bandera == 1) {

                row["idPregSig"] = preguntaSiguiente;

            }

            bandera = 1;
        }

        return nuevaTablaIdSig;

    }
```

Comment: No, me sigue dando el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código que muestras estás poniendo siempre el mismo numero en las 2 columnas por cada iteración del `foreach`, ya que coges el valor de la columna `idSiguiente` y lo pones en las 2 columnas de la misma forma.

Una forma sencilla de hacer lo que buscas es con un `for` y trabajando con los índices del `DataTable`, un ejemplo seria el siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TablaIdSig.Rows.Count -1; i++)
{
    DataRow row = nuevaTablaIdSig.NewRow();
    row["idPregunta"] = TablaIdSig.Rows[i]["idPregunta"]; //Cogemos el número de idPregunta
    row["idPregSig"] = TablaIdSig.Rows[i+1]["idPregunta"]; //Cogemos el siguiente número
    nuevaTablaIdSig.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó de maravilla. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar tener que crear un nuevo datatable usando el `foreach` de las columnas podrias usar directamente

[DataTable.Clone Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clone?view=netframework-4.5)

Para volcar los datos teniendo el id de la pregunta anterior simplemente la conservas por fuera del `foreach`

```
List<DataRow> reverseTablaIdSig = TablaIdSig.AsEnumerable().Reverse().ToList();

int preguntaSiguiente = "0";

foreach (DataRow dr in reverseTablaIdSig.Rows) 
{
    DataRow row = nuevaTablaIdSig.NewRow();
    row["idPregunta"] = dr["idPregunta"];
    row["idPregSig"] = preguntaSiguiente;
    nuevaTablaIdSig.Rows.Add(row);

    preguntaSiguiente = dr["idPregunta"].ToString();
}
```

No deduzco bien el tipo de dato de esa columna `idPregunta` pero sino es una cadena deberias definir un default diferente.

La idea es que en cada iteracion la variable se quede con el id anterior, pero inicias de abajo hacia arriba por eso se revierte el datatable asi lo iteras y la row que quede sin siguiente sea la ultima

Comment: Me resultó con la primer respuesta. muchas gracias!